# Java utility class trouble

Tags: java, architecture

I have some data-structure that requires alphabet as parametr of its constructor. So if I create new instance of it I will need each time supply an alphabet.

Is there easier way?
I think that I can symplify it by usage of static utility class, like this

```
Alphabet {
  public static final eng = "abc...z";
  public static final ua = "абв...я";
}
```

But this doesn't guarantee expandability. I mean yeah, I can simly add some alphabets to such class, but user can't add his own alphabets, for examle russian alphabet.

I can make utility class, which use private instance of HashMap, where **K** is coutry-code and **V** is alphabet, and support get/put methods for user. So this way I can guarantee expandability.
But doesn't it makes all complex?

Edit

Suppose currently I doing so

```
Structure instance = new Structure("abc...z");
//in another class
Structure instance = new Structure("abc...z");
```

By utility class I can do so

```
Structure instance = new Structure(Alphabet.eng);
//in another class
Structure instance = new Structure(Alphabet.eng);
```

Comment: you can use Properties file also and read it in map

Comment: @TipuSultan but is it hard for user to understand why I'm using such class and actually use it?

Comment: How is the alphabet used? Why does user need to add new alphabet? By user do you mean a developer?

Comment: @TipuSultan yeah, but I want define only 3 alphabets by my own and let user add his own alphabets

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak yes, by user I mean developers, which use my structure. User needs to add alphabet to work with it. More formally alphabet defines, which strings structure can hold

Comment: @MikeHerasimov It sounds to me like you should have an interface. Provide a few your own implementations (possibly an enum), while another developer can still create their own implementation. The method that uses this alphabet should accept an interface. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I've add example, what I actually doing, take a look on it please, so as you can see I just don't want to type alphabet couple times

Comment: @MikeHerasimov Exactly what I said. See answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you should have an interface. Provide a few your own implementations (possibly an enum), while another developer can still create their own implementation. The method that uses this alphabet should accept an interface (not your enum).

```
interface Alphabet {
    String characters();
}

enum KnownAlphabet implements Alphabet {
    ENG("abc...z"),
    UA("абв...я");

    private final String characters;

    KnownAlphabet(String characters) {
        this.characters = characters;
    }

    @Override
    public String characters() {
        return characters;
    }
}

class Structure {
    public Structure(Alphabet alphabet) {
        String characters = alphabet.characters();
        // do whatever you were doing with the characters before
    }
}
```

Then your:

```
Structure instance = new Structure(Alphabet.eng);
```

Changes into:

```
Structure instance = new Structure(KnownAlphabet.ENG);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: hmm, this is one of possible approaches, yeah it makes what I want, but with some complexity (+1 btw)

Comment: and this approach is better, then usage of HashMap with country-codes

Comment: Having a program that can be easily extended by other developers never comes for free ;) Also, this approach offers better static typing - your method doesn't accept any `String`, it accepts very specific strings so now this can be documented in the interface.

Comment: about "very specific strings" youre right, however I think that best way will be support two constructors: one for String and another for Alphabet 

why I want to leave constructor with String parametr?
because some users will use only one instance and will newer care about alphabet's reusability