# How to allow others to add custom enums to a class through an API

Tags: java, enums

So I made a class called properties and part of it is as such (snipped because of a lot of repetition)

```
public enum Parameters {
SET_CUSTOM_NAME {
    public void process(Entity entity, Object obj, YamlConfiguration yml, String module) {
        entity.setCustomName(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', String.valueOf(obj)));
    }
},
SET_CUSTOM_NAME_VISIBLE {
    public void process(Entity entity, Object obj, YamlConfiguration yml, String module) {
        entity.setCustomNameVisible((boolean) obj);
    }
},
SET_NO_AI {
    public void process(Entity entity, Object obj, YamlConfiguration yml, String module) {
        NBTUtils.addEntityTag(entity, "NoAI", (boolean) obj);
    }
},
SET_SILENT {
    public void process(Entity entity, Object obj, YamlConfiguration yml, String module) {
        NBTUtils.addEntityTag(entity, "Silent", (boolean) obj);
    }
}
{...};

public abstract void process(Entity entity, Object obj, YamlConfiguration yml, String module);
```

}

These parameters are being called through:

```
Parameters.valueOf(param.getKey().toUpperCase()).process(entity, param.getValue(), yml, module);
```

^ "param" is a cached string in a list. don't mind it.

My only problem is I want to allow others to be able to add their own processes to the enum class so that no one is limited to my own and my own only.
Is this possible?

In other words, is it possible to add a enum to this via an API? What method should I include somewhere that would allow other developers to access the enum class and add their own processes to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enum is supposed to represent a complete set of values. You never add to an anum at runtime, that contradicts the definition.

For what you want to do, you could instead define an interface, and hold a map of the names to the implementations:

```
public interface Parameter {
    public void process(Entity entity, Object obj, YamlConfiguration yml, String module);
}


// Somewhere else
Map<String, Parameter> parameters = ... // Initialise it with yours, allow the user to add their own

parameters.get(param.getKey()).process(entity, param.getValue(), yml, module);
```

Comment: There might be no need for a `Map` at all. OP's implementation of the interface could still stay as enum.

Comment: The map is what allows other users to add their own custom parameters. You can't do that with just an enum.

Comment: It depends on the API that uses the interface. If we have a method which accepts the interface, then there won't be any map. But if we want to iterate over all possible implementations, then the map is needed but you can still add enums to it (since they implement the interface).

Comment: Using an enum to represent the default set is possible, but bad design. The intent is for users to extend the set, which is in contrast with the definition of an enum, where all values are known at runtime. I would rather see static constants than an enum, for the default set.

Comment: Interfaces seem like a good idea! I'll try that and see what happens.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Just because I've never used interfaces and I'm only just reading about them now, I'm supposed to put each parameter into it's own class that implements Parameter now, right? (and implementing the process method)

Comment: Exactly right. And you can make `static final` instances of the default parameters in the interface, for convenience.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson That's great! I'm about to make all the classes as sub classes in my Paramter Class for the sake of compactness because my processes are mostly one liners. http://i.imgur.com/YKUrBwP.png

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson As already said, it all depends on how it is actually used. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317897/java-utility-class-trouble/35318445#35318445) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are not extensible. But you could simply fallback to basic OO: Define an abstract class, track all instances of the class by their name, and create instances for all known use cases:

```
public abstract class Parameters {
    private static final HashMap<String,Parameters> map = new HashMap<>();
    private String name;

    public static Parameters valueOf(String name) {
         return map.get(name);
    }

    public Parameters(String  name) {
         this.name = name;
         map.put(name, this);
    }

    public String name() { return name; }

    public abstract void process(Entity entity, Object obj, YamlConfiguration yml, String module);

    public static final Parameters SET_CUSTOM_NAME = new Parameters("SET_CUSTOM_NAME") {
        public void process(Entity entity, Object obj, YamlConfiguration yml, String module) {
             ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: @SaadArdati that is really up to your needs. A Map allows to retrieve a `Parameters` object by its name, but when you don't need that you can switch to a set or list, whichever is better for your use case.

Comment: @SaadArdati Keep in mind that the JVM usually uses a Map internally, when you use the function `Enum.valueOf()`, so it's not going to be much of a performance difference.